# Punjabi Text not shown properly on Mobile

Tags: android, fonts, typeface

i have used many punjabi fonts as like bulara_f.ttf , anmollipi , Akaash and many more but every time prolem with one word of punjabi [image] "sihari"

Sihari : Sihari is equivalent to i in pin or thin. Hence forth in this module we will denote sihari vowel with /i/.

in my application only this one word is not shown properly as like in following snapshot... please help...

**EDIT**
    i am using this method

```
Typeface myfont;
        myfont=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font.ttf");
    TextView textview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
    //textview.setText("punjabi Text");
    textview.setTypeface(myfont);
}
```

[image]

Comment: are u displaying in textview?

Comment: yes , i am displaying in textview

Comment: Rohit, I am facing the same problem trying to find a solution for this.

Comment: @jyomin, i dnt find problem of this problem till now.

Comment: have you got the solution of sihari problem in the font style

Answer (score 0):

Use `bulara_5.ttf` and run the code on device it will show correct punjabi words

```
mTvAbout = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_about);
        font = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), "bulara_5.ttf");
        mTvAbout.setTypeface(font);
        mTvAbout.setText(" ਜਾਣਕਾਰੀ");
```